# Process tree / Number of processes for fork()

Tags: c, process, fork

I want to know the number of processes created for the below code. I got to know from my instructor the answer is 41 but I am unable to follow the same. Please explain the same with a process tree.

```
  void main() {
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
        fork();
        if(!fork()) {
            execl("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
            fork();
        }
        fork();
     }
     fork();
  }
```

Comment: Did your instructor mention `void main()` (`main` should return `int`) or the use of the undeclared variable `i` or the lack of `#include`s?

Comment: The `fork();` after the `execl()` will not be reached unless `execl()` returns an error (which is unlikely on a Unix-style system where /bin/ls ought to exist).

Comment: @IanAbbott thanks!! That gives a hint. So in those processes where the control has reached execl(), in those processes the fork() commands below them will not be executed.

Comment: Hmm, I now get it to 42 processes :-)

Comment: So including the parent, it is 42 processes. @TedLyngmo can you please also attach the process tree or who you arrived at 42 ?

Comment: @Nick _"So including the parent, it is 42 processes"_ - Yes, exacl.y. I'm thinking of a way to present it in an understandable way.

Comment: You really only need 2 `printf("%d\n", getpid());`s (one before `execl` and one at the end of `main`) to get all the pids. The problem I have is visualizing what goes on in a good way. Perhaps if you add those `printf`s yourself, you can see how it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a homework question. If we would draw a process tree for you, you might get some points now, but you will not learn how to analyze a program, and this may hurt you later. You will learn more by understanding how the program works. (Of course, this program is an academic example and not very useful except for learning.)

I suggest to mark the `fork` calls with letters.

```
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        fork();          /* A */
        if(!fork()) {    /* B */
            execl("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
            fork();      /* C */
        }
        fork();          /* D */
    }
    fork();              /* E */
}
```

Take paper and pencil, write down what happens and draw a tree using the loop counter and the marked `fork` calls.

**Example:**

The program runs a loop for two cycles (0 and 1), the loop continues in all processes.

In parent `P`, loop cycle `0`, `fork` `A` will create child `1`.
`P -(0,A)-> 1`

Still in loop cycle `0`, both `P` and `1` will run the `fork` `B` inside the condition, creating a new child each.
`P -(0,B)-> 2`, `1 -(0,B)-> 3`.

Think about the meaning of the condition and decide which processes run the conditional block.

Think about what happens after `execl`, e.g. process `x` executes `ls`, resulting in ...

Some processes (name them) will reach `D` and create a child each, all will continue with loop cycle `1`...

etc.

<sub>To see what happens you could add some output after every `fork` to display what happens: which loop index, which `fork`, is the process parent or child of this `fork`, PID, parent PID. And before the `execl` display which PID is about to call it. (Note that buffered output like `printf` may show unexpected behavior in combination with `fork`, so it might be better to use `sprintf` and `write`.) Running the program will produce output that could help you to draw a process tree. It is even possible to format the output in a way that a tree could be generated automatically using graphviz or PlantUML. All these are advanced topics.</sub>

Comment: thanks alot! I could follow the and understood the same :)